# Replacing a radio button with a image with CSS that works in Firefox?

Tags: css, image, radio-button, checked

I have a form that people can select a movie they like and I use a radio for the impute. I have replaced it with an image and when its selected it changes to another image. It works just as I want in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox. Here the code..

**CSS**

```
#votetable input[type=radio] {
float: bottom;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border: none;
height: 402px;
width: 275px; 
background: url("hobbit.jpg") left center no-repeat;    
background-size: 402px;
}
#votetable input[type="radio"]:checked {
background: url("select.jpg") left center no-repeat;
}
```

and the html just for more info

**HTML**

```
    <table id="votetable">
        <tr>    <td>
                <label for="movie1"></label>
                <input type="radio" id="movie1" name="movie" value="batman"/>
                </td>

        </tr>
</table>
```

This works great in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox. Is there something I can add to my code to make it work in Firefox? Id like to stick with just CSS and HTML. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe you could try with: -moz-appearance:none, but, i didn't tested it...

Answer (score -1):

I hope this works for you. Note that the `:checked` pseudo class only works in modern browsers. If you want to support older browsers, you'll need a little bit of JavaScript for example to toggle a class.

```
.custom-radio > input {
    /* hide the real <input> element */
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1px;
}

.custom-radio > .real-label {
    /* and use a background image on a <span> instead */
    display: inline-block;
    height: 402px;
    width: 275px;
    background: url("hobbit.jpg") left center no-repeat;
    /* just as an example as I did not have your image */
    border: 2px solid red;
    /* hide the label if you want */
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.custom-radio > input:checked + .real-label {
    background-image: url("select.jpg");
    /* again, just as an example */
    border-color: green;
}
```

…as well as your HTML. As you can see, the `<label>` now wraps around the `<input>` so that when you click it, the `<input>` receives the click as well.

```
<table id="votetable">
    <tr>    
        <td>
            <label class="custom-radio">
                <input type="radio" id="movie1" name="movie" value="batman"/>
                <span class="real-label">label</span>
            </label>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Mind that as you only have 1 radio button, you can only toggle it once…  See it more or less working in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e0sfh695/

Comment: @Andrej do you have an example?

Comment: Simply open your fiddle, make the frame with the result smaller than the label, scroll down and click to select. Page will scroll to the beginning of the label (both in Chrome and FF). I would expect it not to scroll, here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/dcnYM/25/  I removed `inline-block` from the label.

Comment: Updated the example and fiddle by hiding the `input` in a different way.